# How can something be added to an attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

How can something be modified or added to a class?

For example, in the following code what does it mean that `hello` can modify the `a` I used in `__init__`? I still have a lot of uncertainty on OOP, especially the relation between instantiation and other things.

I'm sure it's possible; if so, how can I do it?

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
     
    def hello(self):
```

Comment: It sounds like there's some important context we're missing, perhaps an assignment you're struggling to understand. Your question is unclear. We need that context.

Comment: For example, let's say that I have a method called "add_book". What does it mean to add books to the attribute books? That means in this case, it would look like def__init__ (self, book).

Comment: An "add_book" method would probably involve appending an object representing a book to a list of book objects. It would be a completely separate method from `__init__`, and `__init__` would probably not take a `book` argument.

Comment: Hey @FruDeGames, I just wanted to try and clarify what you're asking. It seems to me like you're asking about how to modify that `self.a` that you referenced in your `__init__` method. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct @thesecretmaster.

Comment: @FruDeGames I've suggested an edit to hopefully make your question reopen-able. You should be able to accept it yourself if you'd like to.

Comment: Can you please clarify what confuses you about modifying attributes? Have you ever modified a variable, say ``a = b = []; a.append(3)``? Have you ever re-assigned a variable, say ``a = b = []; a += [3]``? Do you feel there should be a difference between modifying attributes and variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already successfully adding/modifying the class instance. Namely, `__init__` takes some `a` and *adds* it as the attribute `.a` to the instance `self`. Using the same name for the variable and attribute is incidental -- you could as well use different names:

```
class Bla:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.a = b  # add `b` as attribute `a`
```

Once an attribute is added to an instance, this attribute can by default be read and overridden freely. This applies to the initial method, other methods, and any other function/method having access to the instance.

```
class Bla:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.a = b  # add `b` as attribute `a`

    def lol(self, c):
        self.a = c  # add `c` as attribute `a` (discarding previous values)

    def rofl(self, d):
        self.a += d  # re-assign `self.a + d` as attribute `a`

# external function modifying `Bla` instance
def jk(bla, e):
    bla.a = e  # add `e` as attribute `a` (discarding previous values)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how Bla.lol() can modify the *argument* `a` that is supplied to it, but it can alter the *attribute* `Bla.a` or `self.a` as it is referenced from within the object, which initially has the value of argument `a` assigned to it.

We can have the function `lol` assign a new value to the attribute `a`, in this case I'm going to assume `a` is a string, and extend the string with the phrase `' has been altered'`:

```
>>> class Bla:
...     def __init__(self, a):
...         self.a = a
... 
...     def lol(self):
...         self.a += ' has been altered'
...         
>>> instance = Bla('the arg a')
>>> instance.a  # check a
'the arg a'
>>> instance.lol()  # modifies a
>>> instance.a  # check a again
'the arg a has been altered'
>>> instance.lol()  # we can alter it again, as many times as we run the function
>>> instance.a  # and see it has been altered a second time
'the arg a has been altered has been altered'
```